# In-app генерация java aidl

Tags: in-app-purchases, android

Доброго времени суток.
Наверняка туплю в какой то мелочи - разбираюсь с In-app, в доках пишут что нужно положить файл IInAppBillingService.aidl в com.android.vending.billing. Так как если пакет приложения начинается с com его не удастся опубликовать то пишу свое имя пакета и рядом создаю еще package, выглядит так
[image]
в манифесте пишу  
 Делаю опираясь на пример из sdk и [документацию](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download)

> If you are developing in a non-Eclipse environment: Create the following directory /src/com/android/vending/billing and copy the IInAppBillingService.aidl file into this directory. Put the AIDL file into your project and use the Ant tool to build your project so that the IInAppBillingService.java file gets generated.
>   Build your application. You should see a generated file named IInAppBillingService.java in the /gen directory of your project.

Подскажите как правильно генерировать из aidl java файл, не пользовался раньше ant/
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

советую проделать по шагам вот этот пункт 
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-add-aidl  
У меня была проблема, но решил я именно так ее

Comment: спасибо, действительно не внимательно прочитал и создавал пакеты, вместо того чтобы создавать папки